# Session is returning null exception on DB upgrade

Tags: android, database, sqlite, session

I am sort of newbie in android. I am keeping logged in users' data in a session and redirecting them from login screen to MainActivity when application is started. I am using sth like that in onCreate method of login activity:

```
if(session.isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
```

The user is kept logged in until click logout and run `session.logoutUser();` and it is working like:

```
public void logoutUser(){
    // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();

    // After logout redirect user to Login Activity
    Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
    // Closing all the Activities
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    // Add new Flag to start new Activity
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    // Staring Login Activity
    _context.startActivity(i);
}
```

The problem is that, when I make a db upgrade in MySQLiteHelper class, `session.isLoggedIn()` is still returning true. So the LoginActivity keeps trying to redirect user, and application gives `nullpointerexception` in MainActivity.

I need to check if the database upgraded or not in LoginActivity before redirect to MainActivity, or run `session.logoutUser()` in `onUpgrade()` method. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I defined a public boolean variable in MySQLiteHelper.java class like

`public boolean db_upgrade = false;`

And changed onUpgrade() method like:

```
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older tables if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Players");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Foods");
    // create fresh tables
    this.onCreate(db);
    if(oldVersion != newVersion) {
        db_upgrade = true;
    }
}
```

So I can check if db is upgraded or not with a little change on LoginActivity as:

```
    if (!MySQLiteHelper.db_upgrade) { // if db is not upgraded
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
    }
```